# Binding LinearAxis Interval WPF Toolkit Chart

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `chartingToolKit` in my `XAML` file, and I want to set the interval of the `LinearAxis` dynamically instead of static in my `XAML` file. This is how I do it now:

```
<chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" Interval="1"  Minimum="0" Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="False" />
</chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
```

I tried to do it this way with binding:

```
<chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" Interval="{Binding ChartingInterval}"  Minimum="0" Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="False" />
</chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
```

The binding reference to the property ChartingInterval in my .cs file, like this:

```
public int ChartingInterval
{
    get
    {
        //Should contain more logic, obvious.
        return 1;    
    } 
}
```

But this doesn't seems to work properly. How can I accomplish this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simply because your datacontext isn't set at the object on which you have your property "ChartingInterval".

You should simply set it as follow :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:chartingToolkit="..."
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
    ...
    <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
        <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" Interval="{Binding ChartingInterval}"  Minimum="0" Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="False" />
    </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
    ...
</Window>
```

You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged to allow the property to notify the binding that its value changed, so the binding will update the target value.

Sorry for my english

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it doesn't seems to work. The intervall is just set to a dynamic size by the system..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to reset my chart dynamically in C# for a lineseries. Just replace `LineSeries` by `ColumnSeries` and eliminate the lines that you do not need. Replace also the `DataContext` name with yours, the Style is mine in the XAML windows.resource so you can eliminate it, and so on. Maybe this will help you to start the C# code.

```
//dynamically recreate the chart series1
private void AddSeries()
{
    var series1 = new LineSeries();
    series1.SetBinding(LineSeries.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());
    series1.DataContext = Power;
    series1.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value");
    series1.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key");
    series1.Style = (Style)this.Resources["LineSeriesStyle1"];

    //set initial values:
    LinearAxis independentaxis = new LinearAxis();
    independentaxis.Orientation = AxisOrientation.X;
    independentaxis.ShowGridLines = true;
    independentaxis.Maximum = 60;
    independentaxis.Minimum = 0;
    independentaxis.Title = "Time";
    independentaxis.ShowGridLines = true;
    series1.IndependentAxis = independentaxis;

    //set initial values:
    LinearAxis dependentaxis = new LinearAxis();
    dependentaxis.Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y;
    dependentaxis.ShowGridLines = true;
    dependentaxis.Maximum = 600;
    dependentaxis.Minimum = 0;
    dependentaxis.Title = "Force(n)";
    dependentaxis.ShowGridLines = true;
    series1.DependentRangeAxis = dependentaxis;
    chart1.Series.Add(series1);
}
```